# error when loading aurelia-validation plugin

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I am trying to setup aurelia-validation plugin in my project. I am using VS2015. 
I have installed aurelia-validation plugin using jspm install aurelia-validation command.

Config.js file has been updated "aurelia-validation": "github:aurelia/validation@0.2.7" 
and in jspm_packages/github I see validation@0.2.7 folder.

I have added a plugin in my main.js file.

```
export function configure(aurelia) {

    aurelia.use
        .standardConfiguration()
        .developmentLogging()
        .plugin('aurelia-validation');

    aurelia.start().then(a => a.setRoot());
}
```

and have changed my aurelia-app to aurelia-app="main"

When I start the app I get the following error in Firefox console:

```
Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: aurelia.globalizeResources is not a function
Stack trace:
configure@http://localhost:15724/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/validation@0.2.7/index.js:28:5
loadPlugin/<@http://localhost:15724/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/framework@0.15.0/aurelia-framework.js:34:32
run@http://localhost:15724/jspm_packages/npm/core-js@0.9.18/modules/es6.promise.js:91:43
notify/<@http://localhost:15724/jspm_packages/npm/core-js@0.9.18/modules/es6.promise.js:105:11
module.exports@http://localhost:15724/jspm_packages/npm/core-js@0.9.18/modules/$.invoke.js:6:25
@http://localhost:15724/jspm_packages/npm/core-js@0.9.18/modules/$.task.js:40:9
run@http://localhost:15724/jspm_packages/npm/core-js@0.9.18/modules/$.task.js:27:7
listner@http://localhost:15724/jspm_packages/npm/core-js@0.9.18/modules/$.task.js:31:5
```

I have tried clearing jspm cache with jspm cc command but that didn't help. All my packages are up to date.

What am I missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was a breaking change in Aurelia 0.15.0:

In the commit [fix(all): create a property framework configuration object](https://github.com/aurelia/framework/commit/bab4c776f4266b727e4cf04b04ba409ead3bfeed) 
the `globalizeResources` method was renamed to `globalResources`

Since then (2015.08.13) the aurelia-validation plugin hasn't been updated.

You get the error because the aurelia-validation only supports aurelia 0.14.1 or older. So you have to downgrade your aurelia version to work with the validation plugin until it is not updated.

Comment: not sure if it got moved also - seems like you need to do aurelia.use.globalResources :)

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer is correct.  A quick fix (to avoid downgrading aurelia) would be to manually edit this line:
https://github.com/aurelia/validation/blob/master/dist/system/index.js#L10

in your `jspm_packages\github\aurelia\validation...` folder

Also change any `aurelia.withSingleton` calls to `aurelia.container.registerSingleton`

Comment: This is the better of the two solution.